# anyone know how twiddla accomplished its browsing abilities?

Tags: javascript, html

I realized that you cannot just insert `<iframe src=remote-page-here></iframe>` and expect it to work, and [twiddla](http://www.twiddla.com) is not using any flash, so I'm curious as to how they accomplish the in place browser thing.

If anyone can enlighten me on that it would be great!

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they're doing some interesting things with frames. They're downloading the source of the navigated-to URL, then injecting that source into some wrapper markup, and rendering that HTML into a frame. The URL that's navigated to is thus not remote, but local to twiddla. That frame can then be drawn on with twiddla's crazy JavaScript.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself, though I'd also add that the <base> tag is your friend for this sort of thing.  - Jason from Twiddla